# How to open/pass a file into XMLEventReader

Tags: java, xml, file-io, xml-parsing

I'm trying to create a program that will read in an XML-based file and that will basically rewrite it in a more human friendly way, but I keep running into `XMLStreamException`s.

Here is what I have now

```
`import java.io.File;

/* main purpose of this class is to read and write an XML document
   using tenants of STaX parsing. Eventually this should turn into a 
  class that will trim all but the outer 20% of the page
  */
 public class XMLReader {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    System.out.println("FACTORY:" + factory);

    /*
     //TODO: make input and output file take args from command line
     using the programs mike sent as a reference.

     File file =null;
     if(args.length > 0) {
     file = new File(args[0]);
     }
     */
    InputStream in = null; //initializing the file we will read
    XMLEventReader reader = null; //intializing the eventreader
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("/home/bzifkin/Proteus2/homer/src/main/java/ciir/proteus/parse/1105979_djvu.xml");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not find the file. Try again.");
    }

    try {
        reader = factory.createXMLEventReader(in);
     } 
        catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an XML Stream Exception, whatever that means");
    }
}
```

}

This is the stack trace I get on the `XMLStreamException`

Message: expected start or end tag at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:235)
    at ciir.proteus.parse.XMLReader.main(XMLReader.java:61)

Comment: what do you mean it didn't work. What Exception or Error are you seeing?

Comment: A `FileNotFoundException` and then after that a `XMLStreamException`

Comment: Where is the file located? with `/1105979_djvu` it is expected to be at the root of your filesystem. also if the file has an extension you need to specify it, otherwise -> `FileNotFoundException`!

Comment: I ran `pwd` and got my current path pasted it onto the file name and that worked!! Now all I need to do is figure out why I'm getting the `XMLStreamException`

Comment: ur file is not properly formatted. try to test with a different simple xml file

Comment: Please update your question with the correct path of the file, also print the stack trace of the `XMLStreamException` and add it to your question. add `e.printStackTrace();` to the catch block.

Comment: @A4L Done it should be there.

Comment: @eldjon The xml file has been modified slightly so as to be .djvu as well

Comment: Your file is not valid xml, schould files of format `djvu` contain xml? If Yes then it has to be valid otherwise you wouldn't be able to parse it.

Comment: @A4L they do contain xml, its pretty much the exact same thing really just different qNames

Comment: eventually thats what causes the exception. i dont know the .djvu but seems like not complying with xml.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the comments right, you get a FileNotFoundException first, then XMLStreamException.

That sounds reasonable, because if opening the file fails, your code is printing an error message, but continues to process the undefined (null) InputStream "in".

Do something like this instead:

```
try {
    in = new FileInputStream("/home/bzifkin/Proteus2/homer/src/main/java/ciir/proteus/parse/1105979_djvu.xml");
    try {
        reader = factory.createXMLEventReader(in);
    } 
    catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an XML Stream Exception, whatever that means");
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Could not find the file. Try again.");
}
```